# Upstart: chdir stanza VS cd command

Tags: linux, upstart, init-script

In [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script I can use [`chdir` stanza](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#chdir) to set the working directory. Also I can just execute a normal `cd` command inside my `script` section.

What is the difference between this two approaches? When and why I should use each of them?

Answer (score 4):

In Upstart, you can have more than just one type of script. For example you can have pre/post start and pre/post stop scripts as well. The `chdir` stanza sets a default directory for ALL scripts. The `cd` command will only change the working directory within the scope of the current script.

Comment: Sounds good. That's all?

Comment: That's all I know of. I'm fairly new to Upstart myself. Maybe someone else knows more.